# Webpack dupplicate code

Tags: webpack

I have a project with a lot of components. Components extends components.

The problem is each Component extended creates a chunk with duplicated code.

It has the code of the component extended and if the component is also extended, the chunk contains the code too!

If i create an other component copy of the previous one, it the same problem.
So have a serious problem of duplication code.

How can I fix it ?

```
var Chaplin = require('Chaplin');

var AppComponent2 = require('AppComponent2'); // Extend BaseComponent2 that is extended by BaseComponent

module.exports = AppComponent2.Controller.extend({
    index: function () {
        console.log('hello from AppComponent');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'use strict';

var Promise = require('promise');

module.exports = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    require.ensure([], function () {

        resolve({
            Controller: require('./FooterComponent-controller.js')
        });
    },'FooterComponent');
});
```

Comment: Fixed using promise and chunk name.